# create project from existing source in android ADT 20

Tags: android, adt

where is the option "create project from existing source"  in ADT 20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Eclipse Go to

`File->New->Other->Android->Android Project From Exsisting Source`

Comment: `Invalid project description`.  `... overlaps the location of another project (same project).` Is *not* an ADT project (no .project or .classpath files).  Click "Copy projects into workspace" to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

First go to `File->New->Project->Select a Wizard under Android->Android Project from Existing code ->click next after normal steps such as old ADT in eclipse.`

Like Below Screen Shot:

Step 1 like below screen shot link.

[image]

Step 2 like below screen shot link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to file and then import and there you can import Android Projects

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps,

```
Goto -> File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into WorkSpace
```